# Second call to HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() throws timeout exception

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, timeout

Help... I can't figure out why HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() is throwing a timeout
exception... it ALWAYS occurs when trying to establish the second (and subsequent)
connections using POST. Basically, I am trying to create the connection 
every 30 seconds. Here is the relevent code:

My Main Loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++ ) {

    Log( "Processing: " + students[i].DbID + ";" + students[i].Username + ";" + students[i].Password );

    UserConnection uc = new UserConnection( students[i] );
    uc.ParseAll();


    Log( "Done Processing: " + students[i].DbID + ";" + students[i].Username + ";" + students[i].Password );
}
```

From User Connection:

```
public UserConnection( Student student )
{
    this.student = student;

    this.cookies = new CookieContainer();
    this.InitCookies();

    this.courses = new List<Course>();
}


private void InitCookies()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( baseUri );
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.CookieContainer = this.cookies;

    req.GetResponse();


}

public void ParseAll()
{
    ParseCourseInfo(); //get info for each class
    .
    .
    .
}

private void ParseCourseInfo()
{
    HtmlDocument page = GetPage( "POST", homeUri, "username=" + student.Username + "&password=" + student.Password + "&testcookies=1" );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The following exception is occuring in GetPage:

```
29/07/2012 1:04:22 PM : Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out
Source: System
Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at URCoursesParserV2.UserConnection.GetPage(String method, Uri pageUri, String queryString) in UserConnection.cs:line 167
```

Here is the GetPage code where the problem is:

```
private HtmlDocument GetPage( string method, Uri pageUri, String queryString = "" )
{
    Stream data = null;
    HttpWebResponse res = null;
    HttpWebRequest req = null;
    try {

        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( pageUri );
        req.CookieContainer = this.cookies;
        req.Timeout = 1000 * 10; //10 seconds - I've also tried leaving it as default
        req.KeepAlive = false; ////I've also tried leaving it as true.

        if( method.ToUpper() == "POST" ) {
            req.Method = "POST";

            if( queryString != "" ) {
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( queryString );
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

                using( data = req.GetRequestStream() ) { //////////////EXCEPTION HERE ON SECOND ITERATION
                    data.Write( postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length );
                    data.Close();
                }
            }

        } else if( method.ToUpper() == "GET" ) {
            req.Method = "GET";

            if( queryString != "" ) {
                pageUri = new Uri( pageUri.ToString() + '?' + queryString );
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        HtmlDocument page = null;
        using( res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() ) {
            using( data = res.GetResponseStream() ) {
                page = new HtmlDocument();
                page.Load( data );
            }
        }
        return page;

    } catch(WebException e) {
        URCoursesParser.Log( e );
        return null;

    } catch( Exception e ) {
        URCoursesParser.Log( e );
        return null;

    } finally { ///data and res probably don't need to be checked here now because of 'using' blocks
        if( data != null ) {
            data.Close();
            data = null;
        }
        if( res != null ) {
            res.Close();
            res = null;
        }
        if( req != null ) {
            req.Abort();
            req = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas!?! The first iteration is always fine. If I terminate the program and restart the first iteration is again fine... It's always the second and subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This could be part of the problem:

```
private void InitCookies()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( baseUri );
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.CookieContainer = this.cookies;
    req.GetResponse();
}
```

Here you're not disposing of the response... so it's not returning the connection to the pool.

It's not really clear what this method is meant to do, but you *should* dispose of the response:

```
using (req.GetResponse()) {}
```

Comment: You are the MAN! Should have saved myself 4 hours muckin with stuff and came here sooner.

Here I just need to establish a connection to initialize some cookies so that I'm able to login during the post request.

Comment: @Cailen: Wouldn't it initialize the cookies if you just set them later on when you're sending a "real" request? Maybe not...

Comment: Once again Jon Skeet saves the day

Comment: Thanks, Jon! I've been staring at this code for two days!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I explicitly wanted to exit the method before waiting for the response. I set the Timeout of the request to 100 milliseconds, and that seemed to fix it for me.